# Wide variety or wide choice (in context)

Tags: word-choice, word-in-context

> Fill in the Blanks
>
> We offer a wide ....... of classes in this school.
>
> 1. case
> 2. variety
> 3. part
> 4. choice

For me a wide variety of classes imply that we have various classes (in different subjects) and wide choice of classes imply that you have a lot of classes to choose from (and attend in). But the questions of the book in which I found this question have one valid answer and I don't know which one is right and I am not native so I cannot be sure about the feeling I get from each answer.

So, which answer is right (or more appropriate)?

Comment: It's impossible to tell from the given context.  *The question is flawed*.  "Variety" sounds best, but I don't think "choice" is wrong (although I prefer "selection" in this context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a strictly technical standpoint, both 2. and 4. are grammatically correct. An answer depends on the intention of the question.

- You could have 20 courses that cover 5 subjects in total: this shows a wide choice of classes.
- You could have 10 courses that cover 10 subjects in total: this shows a wide variety of classes.

But, having said that, I find *a wide choice* to be awkward because I'm not used to hearing it—I'm not even sure I'e ever heard it. (I'm used to *a wide selection* instead.)

If the word is *choice*, I think that *large choice* is more common. (Which is not an available option.)

In contrast, I've heard both *wide variety* and *large variety*. Don't ask me why; English is annoyingly illogical.

In conclusion, I would choose 2. because it is both grammatically correct and more common.